# Does std::move need to be combined with std::forward when using forwarding references?

Tags: c++, c++14

Does std::move need to be combined with std::forward when using universal references?  For example, which of the following two pieces of code is correct?

```cpp
void bar(auto && x) {
    auto y(std::move(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)));
}
```

or

```cpp
void bar(auto && x) {
    auto y(std::move(x));
}
```

Basically, I want to move the memory of x into y and I don't care if it's an l-value reference or an r-value reference.  Certainly, I don't want `const` values here.

Comment: No. Only use one of them.

Comment: Both of them are equivalent to `auto y(std::move(x))` which does **not** forward, just cast to an rvalue reference. Remember that `std::forward<T>()` is a conditional cast to an rvalue- or lvalue-reference (depending on the value category), while `std::move()` is an *unconditional* cast to an rvalue-reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `move` will suffice if you want to move **regardless** of the value category of the argument.  
`forward` is superfluous in that case as `move(forward(x))` is always an rvalue, no matter what `forward(x)` is.

If you only wanted to move depending on whether the argument to `bar` was an rvalue, you should use `forward` on its own, which propagates the value category.

Comment: Now, even though the call to `forward` is superfluous, isn't the prototype for `move` technically a universal reference, which suggested the forward?

Comment: @wyer33 Just imagine `move` as a funtion that returns an rvalue referring to its argument. And imagine `forward` as a function that returns an lvalue or rvalue reference referring to its argument. The difference that `forward` makes in the expression, if any, will be eradicated by `move` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**/!\ BEWARE /!\**

Using `std::move` for a universal reference can be a very bad idea and highly recommended to avoid :

```
auto name = getName(); // std::string getName();
bar(name);
// 'name' value has been moved... And its value now is unknown, empty at best.
```

---

`move(forward(x))` is bad style and shouldn't be used.

You should use `std::move` for rvalue references and `std::forward` for universal references. Cf. formal definitions.

`auto&&` is a universal reference, therefore what you should write is :

```
void bar(auto&& x) {
    auto y(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x));
}
```

Comment: auto as function argument? Which version of C++ are you using, C++21?

Comment: Six60r: it's an *abbreviated function* which is not a part of the standard (yet), @ViktorSehr fyi